# cleaning up event listeners in custom elements

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

When registering event listeners in `attachedCallback`, is it my responsibility to ensure that these are removed again in `detachedCallback`?

As illustrated in the minimal sample below, the pattern is rather predictable so I'm wondering whether perhaps the browser already takes care of this?

```html
<my-element>0</my-element>
```

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
    createdCallback() {
        this.update = this.update.bind(this);
    }

    attachedCallback() {
        this.addEventListener("click", this.update);
    }

    detachedCallback() {
        this.removeEventListener("click", this.update);
    }

    update() {
        this.textContent = Math.random();
    }
}

document.registerElement("my-element", {
    prototype: MyElement.prototype
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should remove `Event Listeners` in the `detachedCallback()` method when they are attached to objects like `window` or `document`, that will persist after the life of your Custom Element.

But if the `Event Listener` is attached to the Custom Element itself (or to any element inside its proper DOM), it will be removed at the moment its owner element is destroyed.
That is, in your example above, you wouldn't have to call `removeEventListener()` against `this`.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was hoping to hear - thank you!